# R: Error when using "Tabasco" function for Clusteranalysis

Tags: r, error-handling, cluster-analysis

I´m trying to do a clusteranalysis with my data. I have observations of fish abundance in different transects. Now I wanna where the similarities between the distributions of the species are and how the fish communities are distributed in the different habitats.
I found a really good example of clusteranalysis, where they are using the "dune" data to do this. Besides the obvious cluster functions, they use vegemite and tabasco function, to get a figure, where similar species are next to each other.
So I tried to do the same for my dataset, but all I get is this error:

Error in if (any(x < 0)) stop("function cannot be used with negative data values") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

First of all, I don´t know where R is seeing the negative value, since I just have abundances, there can´t be a negative value. I also checked with the is.na function, but it couldn´t find any missing values either. The other thing is, I don´t know which argument is used in tabasco to indicate how R should handle missing values. I tried na.action, but it doesn´t work. 
I would be happy if someone could help me.
So this is the example script, where it works perfectly fine:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
d <- vegdist(dune)
ccom <- hclust(d, method="complete")
plot(ccom, hang=-1)
cl <- cutree(ccom, 3)
ord <- cmdscale(d)
ordiplot(ord)
ordihull(ord, cl, lty=3)
den <- as.dendrogram(ccom)
x <- scores(ord, display = "sites", choices = 1)
oden <- reorder(den, x)
vegemite(dune, oden)
tabasco(dune, ccom)
```

And this is my script:

```
transekte<-read.csv2("C:/Users/Nancy/Dropbox/Masterarbeit/Statistik_Neu/Arten_MW_Transekte.csv")
library(vegan)
d<-vegdist(transekte,method="bray",upper=FALSE)
clusters<-hclust(d,method="complete")
plot(clusters,hang=-1)
clustercut<-cutree(clusters,2)
clustercut
table(clustercut)
rect.hclust(clusters,2,border="red")
ord <- cmdscale(d)
ordiplot(ord)
ordihull(ord, clustercut, lty=3)
den <- as.dendrogram(clusters)
x <- scores(ord, display = "sites", choices = 1)
oden <- reorder(den, x)
vegemite(transekte, oden,scale="log")
tabasco(transekte[2:37,], clusters)
```

I needed to scale my data because vegemite only accepts one-character values. And I excluded the first line for tabasco, because if I just say "transekte" it keeps telling me there is an error, because one of the rows isn´t = or > than zero. It seems to include the species names for the analysis and this of course triggers an error.
Heres a link to my Dropbox with the csv file and my R script:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y8xzq0bs6mus727/AADmasrXxUp6JTTHN5Gr9eufa?dl=0
I would be really grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: `tabasco` passes any extra arguments to `heatmap`  which takes `na.rm=TRUE`.  You might give that a try.

Comment: No, sorry. That doesn´t do it either. I still get the error message.